# Python - Order nested list in alphabetical way

Tags: python, list, nested, alphabetical, sorting

I have the following list:

```
["stephane", "philippe", "hélène", ["hugo", "jean-michel", "fernand"], "gustave"]
```

And I would like to order it like this:

```
["gustave", "hélène", ["fernand", "hugo", "jean-michel"], "philippe", "stephane"]
```

NB: If there is a nested list following a user, this list must stay to the right of this user.

In addition to that all nested lists works the same way. It's recursive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used Ned's proposal and came up with this:

```
d = {
    "stephane": {}, 
    "philippe": {}, 
    "helene": {
        "hugo": {}, 
        "jean-michel": {},
        "fernand": {},
    }, 
    "gustave": {},
}

def sort_dict_as_list(d):
    sorted_list = []
    for k, v in sorted(d.items()):
        if k:    
            sorted_list.append(k)
        if v:
            sorted_list.append(v)
    return sorted_list

def sort_recursive(d):
    if d:
        for k, v in d.items():
            d[k] = sort_recursive(v)
        return sort_dict_as_list(d)
    else:
        return d

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print sort_recursive(d)
```

Output

```
python sortit.py
['gustave', 'helene', ['fernand', 'hugo', 'jean-michel'], 'philippe', 'stephane']
```

I haven't tested it thoroughly, but it's a starting point. I was trying to solve it with a list as a data structure, but I ended up nesting recursive functions and it was way too ugly... Ned's proposal was really good.

Comment: I guess the OP already has some recursive code consuming those lists.  I'd keep them as dicts all the way and just consume them in sorted() order.  BTW, if the purpose is just pretty debugging, the pprint module sorts dicts recuresively.

Answer (score 6):

Your data sounds like it would be better represented as a dictionary.  Lists where consecutive elements have a special relationship sound odd.

If you instead represented your data like this:

```
{
  "stephane": {}, 
  "philippe": {}, 
  "hélène": {
    "hugo": {}, 
    "jean-michel": {},
    "fernand": {},
  }, 
  "gustave": {},
}
```

Then you can simply sort the keys of the dictionaries to get the order you want.

Comment: Beat me to it :) And if Acti67's on a reasonably recent Python version, he/she might like to use an [`OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Comment: @Tim I assume you know, but for those who do not, OrderedDict is _ordered_, not _sorted_. In order to have it sorted, you'd have to make sure you add the key-value pairs in sorted order.